# Is it correct to say that curvature $\kappa = \frac{|a|}{|v|^2}$?

Tags: soft-question, vectors, curvature

With : $ r=$ position vector , $v=r'=$ velocity vector , $a = v'=$ acceleration vector , and $T=\frac{v}{|v|}= $  unit tangent vector, one formula for curvature $ \kappa$  is :

$\kappa = \frac{|T'|}{|r'|}= \frac{|T'|}{|v|}$.

I'd like to know whether the above formula is equivalent to :

$\kappa = \frac{|a|}{|v|^2}\space\space $?

I tried this derivation:

$T'= [\frac {v} {|v|}]' = \frac{1}{|v|} [v]' = \frac{1}{|v|}a$.

$\kappa = \frac{|T'|}{|v|}= \frac{\big|\frac{1}{|v|}a\big|}{|v|}= \frac{ \big|\frac{1}{|v|}\big||a|} {|v|}= \frac{|a|}{|v|^2}$.

Could you please tell me whether this attempt at deriving the alledged formula does contain any algebra mistake, particularly mistakes regarding absolute values.

Comment: This derivation only works if $\| \vec{v}\|$ is constant, but otherwise, yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen this point!